# How to connect to SQL Server using Pyodbc in Databricks?

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, databricks

I'm trying to connect to a database in an on prem SQL Server but I'm getting this error that I'm not quite understanding. Apparently when I run this in data-bricks it can't find the driver I'm specifying.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code and error as text. Pasted images are not searchable and would not serve to help anyone else in the community trying to solve the same issue(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this.

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \ 
    .builder \ 
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath","mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar") \
    .appName("Python Spark Data Source Example") \ 
    .getOrCreate()

dbDF = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url","jdbc:sqlserver://your_server_name.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=your_database_name") \ 
    .option("dbtable","dbo.ml_securitymastersample") \ 
    .option("user","your_user_name") \ 
    .option("nullValue", ["","N.A.","NULL"]) \ 
    .option("password","your_password").load()


# display the dimensions of a Spark DataFrame
def shape(df):
    print("Shape: ", df.count(), ",", len(df.columns))

# check % of missing values across all columns
dbDf.select([count(when(col(c).isNull), c)).alias(c) for c in dbDf.columns]).show()
```

Does that work for you?